# Managing CakePHP Plugins with Composer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, dependency-management, composer-php

Over time I've developed a number of CakePHP Plugins that I reuse across projects. What I'd like to do is start managing them like dependencies.

My initial thoughts are that I should make each plugin a private composer library. However, as composer manages dependencies from a single vendors folder, would it be wise to and / or feasible to link symlink the CakePHP Plugin directory to the vendors folder?

Or is there a better solution for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CakePHP plugins you should look at the composer/installers project that helps put them in the right folder: https://github.com/composer/installers

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. Thank you.